# Check for the presence of elements at same xpath level in multiple xpaths

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <root> 
     <note> 
     <heading>Reminder</heading>  
     <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
   </note>  
   <note>   
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
   </note>  
   <note> 
     <heading>Reminder</heading>
    </note> 
</root>
enter code here
```

Hi All,

Encountering with a problem in xslt. Any of your help would be greatly helpful.

Need to check for presence of elements in the note tag.
If only /body element is present in /note I need to print a set of statements and if only /heading element is present I need to print a different set of statements.
How can i check for the presence of elements in the root/note elements since all the **note** elements are at same xpath.

When I am receiving multiple note elements with different combinations of inner elements how to check for the presence of elements at one particular  note element.

Comment: Looks like you want someone write code for you... Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question appropriately

Comment: You should show what you have tried, what you expected and any errors you received. The people on stackoverflow are more likely to make useful suggestions on how to fix your code than they are to write a solution from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all `<note>` elements which have a `<heading>`, but no `<body>` with this XPath statement:

> /root/note[heading and not(body)]

Similar solutions apply for `<note>` elements without `<heading>` or with both, `<heading>` and `<body>`:

> /root/note[not(heading) and body]
>
> /root/note[heading and body]

Please note the comments to your question too, about how to write good questions on Stackoverflow.
Especially with such ximple XML input as yours, you can use online testbeds for XML / XPath, e.g. http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath or http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm to find the XPath expressions you need.